# How to populate the python dictionary object that support multi line values for dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using python and reading from ".txt" file and populating  python dictionary in "Key: value" pair as shown below.

Content of sample file is shown below:

```
product: osName
customers: verizon    
class: CL1
file_location: /opt/test.txt
Remarks: This is multi line data. This is line - 1 of remarks field. 
This is line - 2 of remarks field. 
This is line - 3 of remarks field. 
category: software
```

My code to read from the file and populate the python dictionary is shown below:

```
with open(txt_file) as f:
  for l in f:
    key_value = l.strip().split(':',1) 
    txtdict[key_value[0].strip()] = key_value[1].strip()
```

Above solution works fine as long as keys and it's values are in one line only.

Wondering how can I populate the python dictionary object that can support multi line values for any given key?

Thanks for the answer. Wondering why this question is marked as not focused question.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't see an actual issue here.

Comment: Multi lines are not picking up as values. This is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accurately with `csv.reader` module and specific check:

```
import csv

with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', skipinitialspace=True)
    res = {}
    prev_key = ''
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 2:
            k, v = row
            res[k] = v
            prev_key = k
        else:
            res[prev_key] += f'\n{row[0]}'

    print(res)
```

The output:

```
{'Remarks': 'Line one\nLine 2 \nLine 3 of Remarks.',
 'category': 'software',
 'class': 'CL1',
 'customers': 'verizon',
 'file_location': '/opt/test.txt',
 'product': 'osName'}
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error at this line:  File "test1.py", line 69
    res[prev_key] += f'\n{row[0]}'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Ammad, check your Python version

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
$ python3 test1.py
  File "test1.py", line 69
    res[prev_key] += f'\n{row[0]}'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

Comment: When i removed 'f' from this statement, it works. res[prev_key] += '\n{row[0]}'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wondering why this question is marked as not focused question.

Answer (score 1):

Add an if statement after you get key_vale

```
with open(txt_file) as f:
  for l in f:
    key_value = l.strip().split(':',1)
    if len(key_value) > 1:
        txtdict[key_value[0].strip()] = key_value[1].strip()
    else:
        txtdict[key_value[0].strip()] = None
```